# Pagination with page number elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, backend

so i have a api request for example `product?page=1&size=30` and the api response should be:

```
{
   'data':[//array of data],
   'meta': {
      'page': 1,
      'total_page': 10
      'total_data': 300
      'total_data_on_page': 30
   }
}
```

we can achieve this with limit offset elasticsearch api but it's not recommended, so we can use scroll api, but scroll api is sequential search if we want to go to next page we have to pass scroll id but what if frontend want to go to page 5 directly.

how to handle that in back end? (i use python as backend)

Comment: `from/size` is not recommended up until 10000 records (by default). But it's perfectly ok to paginate below that, and you can also modify that limit if your use case requires it and your cluster handles it well. The key here is testing on your own environment and see how it works. Maybe 99% of your users will never go past page 10, who knows...

Comment: yes we can but the problem is i have million records to paginate @Val

Comment: And do you expect to often paginate that far?